# Can't connect to Bluetooth in linux

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth

When I tried to connect my headset to Linux it is telling that `Connection Failed: No audio endpoints registered` .

[image: this is error in gui]

The Bluetooth service is up and running

[image]

I have no idea what to do

please anyone help me with this issue.

Comment: Please don't paste pictures but only command line output (if possible). The bluetooth obviously logged error messages, have you searched for those? Does your headset connect to other devices, e. g. your phone or a different computer?

Comment: Yes, my headset is working fine. It will connect to other devices. The Bluetooth was working fine till yesterday and don't know what went wrong today . Thank you for the replay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this `sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth && apt purge pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`

And it solved the problem